# Spam contacts is saving in DB

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am using `Sitecore 9 Update 2`, I have created one `Form` also I have applied `Google Visible Recaptcha` which is available in `Form Extension Module` but still I can see lots of spam `Contacts` in DB. Does anyone have a solution to stop spam contacts?